# Why can't I programatically create a location field in a node?

Tags: nodes, entities, location

I'm trying to programmatically create a node with a location field, but I'm not able to do it. I have done it in a similar project and it works fine. I use the Entity API module to create the nodes, with this code.

```
 $localizationmap = array(
   'latitude' => $item['field_mapa']['latitude'],
   'longitude' => $item['field_mapa']['longitude'],
   //other elements added here (province, postal_code, country [es, en,...],additional, ...)
 );
 $entity->field_mapa->set($localizationmap);
```

I checked the values that are given to the array and they're OK. 
Drupal log contains the following error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_mapa. en
>   EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (línea 335 de
>   /var/www/vhosts/drupal/litoral.interdigital.biz/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

`field_mapa` exists and it is the name of the location field I'm trying to fill.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply because the stable version of the Location module [doesn't support Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/node/1186868).

There's a patch [here](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/location_entity-1186868-53.patch) that claims to provide the missing support, obviously use with caution on a dev version of the site first.

Comment: Thank you, the "Location Entity (location_entity)" module was not active. It works fine now.